# Use a button on LCD shield to pause the code

Tags: lcd

I'm creating a Temperature logging device with thermocouple K and SD card breakout and a RGB LCD Shield Kit w/ 16x2 Character Display (with buttons).

Everything runs ok: temperature displaying on the LCD and logging on txt file on the micro SD card work well

Now I try to configure button on the shield

1. button UP to reset measurements and timer , it works
2. button Down to pause measurements, then when pushed again, continue measurements. I don't know how to do that (how to go out the while condition).

   ```
    if (buttons) {

   if (buttons & BUTTON_UP) {

     lcd.clear();
     lcd.print("RESET ");
     if (SD.exists("datalog.txt")) {

       SD.remove("datalog.txt");
       File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
     }

     else {

       // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
       // so you have to close this one before opening another.
       File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
       // if the file is available, write to it:

     }
    StartTime = millis();

     delay(500);

   }
   if (buttons & BUTTON_DOWN) {
     lcd.clear();
     lcd.print("STOP");
     while (buttons & BUTTON_DOWN){

         ;
     }
   ```

   }

I already thank you for your help,

Vincent

Comment: think about your first two `if` statements .... why are you testing `buttons` in the second `if` statement? .... you already tested it in the first `if` statement .... same with the last `if` statement ..... also, check the `while (buttons & BUTTON_DOWN){` statement at the bottom ..... do you think that the values of `buttons` and `BUTTON_DOWN` will ever change? .... if you think that they will change, then what changes them?

Comment: This way of testing the buttons comes from the example given with the adafruit RGB LCD shield library. I tried not to re-test "buttons" in the IF statement after the first if(buttons) but the lcd diplays all statements of the next if(BUTTON_DIRECTION) like all the if test give a TRUE. Sorry it is difficult to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saying much about how `buttons` is valorized or its data type, but assuming it is a numeric variable which gets somehow set by, let's say a `readButtons()` function, then consider the following snippet replacing your *while-loop*:

```
do {
  delay(10);
  // re-evaluate whatever sets the buttons variable
  buttons = readButtons();
while(!(buttons & BUTTON_DOWN));
```

The loop above will continue until the button down is pressed and it's a little resilient regarding contact bouncing, but not 100% reliable, so I assume the `readButtons()` performs also some debouncing.

Comment: Thank you Roberto, you have seen right. I'm using the LCD shield library, with a lcd.readButtons function.

Comment: @Vincent if this solves your problem then please accept the answer so that others will be able to use it as a reference